# Error with songs package using external files "input" statement

Tags: input, songs

As an example, I created a songbook with 5 songs.  The five songs are on separate files included on the main document

```
input{../songs/song1.tex}
...
input{../songs/song5.tex}
```

The printout is as follows: Page 1: songs 1&2;  Page 2:  ".tex" printed on a blank page; Page 3: songs 3&4; Page 4: song#5. 
I get no errors (.tex" marks on a blank page) if a) I merge all files into a single tex file. or b) if I only print the first 4 songs.

The log file shows for song # 5

```
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []
```

If I switch song#5 with song#3, I get the following:
Page 1: songs 1&2;  Page 2: song#5; Page 3: ".tex" printed on a blank page; Page 4: song#3.
and the log file does not complain about song#5.  It indicates "underfull \vbox error" for song # 4, that previously was OK before moving song#5 to be in the position of song#3.

Any hints where to troubleshoot?
[image: Error in songs pacage]

Comment: Have you tried to remove the file extension from your `input` statements? Does the error appear then, too?

Comment: All my input statements had the extension ".tex", except for one filename where there was a space before the dot " .tex"   By deleting the extra space on the filename the problem now is gone.  I was not aware that the input statement does not need the extension in it, so I decided to delete all extension on the input statements on my actual songbook with 100+ songs to make it simpler and more readable.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the `songs` package, you should usually be placing songs in `.sbd` files and including via

```
\input{my_songs.sbd}
```

You can include as many files as you want. Each file can have as many songs as you wish. I generally break mine up into categories, so one file for a specific category with a separate index, e.g., `my_songs.sbd` would contain:

```
\beginsong{Song Title}[
  words={A. Author, B. Author},
  music={A. Composer, B. Composer}
  ]
\beginverse
\[A]Cool Lyrics...
\endverse
\endsong

\beginsong{Song 2}...
```

and then in `main.tex`:

```
\cleartorightpage
\showindex{New Song Category}{my-category}
\begin{songs}{my-category}
\input{my_songs.sbd}
\end{songs}
```

Comment: How do you proceed if you want to show only two particular songs of a .sbd file containing many songs?